# how to perform join on Mongodb using python

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I need to read 2 collections data from MongoDB in Python,I am new to it and can't able to resolve this.

Collection1:

```
_id:2382852367
approved_account:null
asset:null
asset_bundle:Object
auction_type:"dutch"
```

Collection2:

```
id:objectid(61deb3aa10154565d187ed79),
Amount:144.44Ξ ($683,971)
From:null
To:null
```

In collection1 its simple id and in collection2 its objectid
I have no idea how to compare object id and simple id and how to perform inner join on these 2 collections.
And i also want to pass dynamic variable to the join so i can get the results by just passing another id value.

Comment: You use an aggregation [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to perform a "join" operation between two related collections in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$lookup** if you desire to perform some operation like **JOIN** in MongoDB.

You can find more about the same here: [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)